# How to access a data element of a CSV file?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a CSV file as my data set. I am using this code below to load it :

`var dataset = d3.csv("mydata.csv");`

My question is how I can have access to the elements inside the dataset var. As I checked, dataset variable is an object. Imagine I need the data element in row 4 and column 7, how can I get that piece of data?

Comment: it should be an array object, like `[
  {"Year": "1997", "Make": "Ford", "Model": "E350", "Length": "2.34"},
  {"Year": "2000", "Make": "Mercury", "Model": "Cougar", "Length": "2.38"}
]` as mentioned in documentation

Answer (score 0):

dataset will only be available in the callback function

```
d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(dataset) {
   dataset = data;
   console.log(dataset)
});
```

Try something like this.

Answer (score 0):

This part of d3 is asynchronous, meaning that your javascript code doesn't sit and wait at that statement until the CSV data is loaded as you might be used to from other languages. Instead, you tell d3 what function should be called once the data is available, and work within it from there. The function can either be defined elsewhere in your code, or (more typically), defined within the d3 function call. Some examples:

```
/* Do something with every row */
d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(data) {
  /* Data has been read and is available as an array of 'row' objects */
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    /* Each row has the variable name 'd': 'columns' can be accessed as object properties */
    console.log(+d['Column name']}); //+d ensures conversion to numbers if that is what you need, at first everything is text
  }); //Close the function and .forEach(...) call
}); //Close the function AND the .csv(...) call

/* Just get one value */
d3.csv(csvfile, function(data) {
  /* Read data from row 4 and some column */
  console.log(+data[3]['Column name']}); //As before, but I'm assuming you know the name of column '7'
}); //Close the function AND the .csv(...) call
```